# How To add Gmail Account Credentials in Static way to Access that account in Android App

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-account

I am doing an android app which uses only my Google account. I want to integrate my Gmail Account in my Android app. So each user who uses my app can use my Google account only .  I want to set my Google account in static without using AccountManager Obj to display all email in their Mobiles.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Gmail account cannot be bind to multiple device (there is a limit ... i don't know exactly but i know it)
Google keep rights to disable those account, check in google account android policy.

You got to let people use their own google play account.

Comment: I found one in Developer site check this Url:  https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html#Security          I don't know Whether it belongs to me or not .

Comment: yes but security checks that this accounts is not bind to not many devices... the error provides from google account policy on backend. Not on android.